# Script that start/stop programs based on if connected to wlan or not

Tags: wireless-networking, script, synology

I would like a script that automatically enables Surveillance station on my Synology NAS when i leave home (my phone dissconnect from my WLAN).

Do you have any idea how to solve this?

Python?

Comment: You could give your phone a static IP address based on it's mac address and setup a ping loop if it's pingable. Are those options in your setup?